# Service Fabric Service Templates in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

I'm attempting to add Service Fabric Service templates in addition to the default ones such as "Stateless Service" etc. to start making services quicker.

Visual studio has export template and VSIX Project Templates options, but these templates appear only in New Project not in "add new Service Fabric Service" in a service fabric application.

The other issue is that in "add new Service Fabric Service" it automatically adds the new service to the Service Fabric Application ApplicationManifest.xml, which the other template methods don't seem to do.

After snooping around visual studio files it seems that the service fabric service templates are stored in a Visual Studio extension, however when trying to add new XML files as Service Templates and including them in manifest.xml they did not show up.

Any suggestions to how service fabric service templates could be added to VS?

Answer (score 0):

> but these templates appear only in New Project not in "add new Service Fabric Service" in a service fabric application.

Not sure I understand it right, but if you are looking for a way to add multiple service fabric services to your Service Fabric Application solution/project - after some time messing around (it is not intuitive) you have to:

1. click on the `Service Fabric Application` project (the one with the 5-dot orange star)
2. click `Add`
3. then choose `New Service Fabric Service`

It will add an additional service fabric service (with the whole service fabric service template) to your service fabric application.
[image]

**PS**.: The above is true for VS 2022.